# Node JS runs on local dev machine but not on active server

Tags: node.js, vue.js, server

My Problem:
My goal is to send weekly mails and for a test I made with the modules node-schedule and nodemailer a website which should send me every minute an email.
My issue:
when I'm running it on my local machine (Windows OS) on the localhost everything works, but as long as I'm uploading it on the server I'm getting:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ett2l.png

On english:
The website is not reachable
g.ch has refused connection.
Try the following:

Check connection
Check proxy and firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The server has the same node js version as the client. The Server is a linux Debian server version 10.4 and the computer I'm programing on has the windows 10 OS.

I've tried to add the following thing to my server.js:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
    
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "chestonag-ch.mail.protection.outlook.com", // hostname
    secure: false, // use SSL
    port: 25, // port for secure SMTP
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'no-reply-mailer@company.ch', // sender address
        to: 'name@company.ch', // list of receivers
        cc: '', // Comma separated list or an array
        subject: 'test upgrde nodemailer subject', // Subject line
        html: '<b>Hello world </b>' // html body
    };

const job = schedule.scheduleJob('30 * * * * *', function() {

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("/sendmail error");
            console.log(error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent: " + info.response);
            socketTimeout: 30 * 1000 // 0.5 min: Time of inactivity until the connection is closed
            transporter.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }

        transporter.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
  

      });
    
    });
```

and the same thing to one of my .js files in the routes.
That you know: The project is with vue.
I have a client side and a server side and my changes were only on the server side.
When I run it local it worked and on the server it didn't and the logs were also empty.

if anyone has an idea how to fix that or an alternative solution, please let me know.

If it's good to know: my goal at the end is to make an emailing system, where you can subscribe to channels and unsubscribe them to receive weekly mails.

Comment: What is the full error code you got?